Primary Key Value conflict in Entity Framework
I'm using Entity Framework to mapping a Postgres database which has three tables - Products, ProductCategories and ProductImages. If I have a blank database, when I insert a new record, I can see the primary key Id started from 0 in three tables, however after seeding a few of records (in my case 30 records) in the tables, then when I try to insert a new record to the database, I receive an error message saying Key value conflict... etc. I guess it's because it still tries to start with a key value which is conflict to the dummy records in the database? if it's the case is there any workaround like set the Primary Key Id started at 31?
Here is my DbContext file:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
        
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext(DbContextOptions<ProductContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Models.Product> Products { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Models.ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Models.ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; } = default!;
}

Here is the three model files:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    
namespace Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        // [Key]
        // public int Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    
        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    
        [ForeignKey("ProductCategory")]
        public int? ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
        public ProductCategory? ProductCategory { get; set; }
    
        [ForeignKey("ProductImage")]
        public int? ProductImageId { get; set; }
        public ProductImage? ProductImage { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    
namespace Models
{
    public class ProductCategory
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)] // Adjust the maximum length as needed
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    
namespace Models
{
    public class ProductImage
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)] // Adjust the maximum length as needed
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    
        [MaxLength(500)] // Adjust the maximum length for description
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }
}

And here is the AddProduct function in the ProductRepository file
public async Task AddProductAsync(Product product)
{
    _context.Products.Add(product);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}


After seeding you can set the sequence like following :
ALTER SEQUENCE Products_id_seq RESTART WITH 31;

Thank you @YBB. It still does not work and I think it's a Postgres thing with Entity Framework. I will have put in a new question to address this.
